# The page isn't redirecting properly in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am trying to publish my website to the server .So i published that and i got a lot of errors,i fixed them ,i get another error `The page isn't redirecting properly in asp.net` when i call the url .

When i call a picture from my website for example `127.0.0.1/i.png` it works and the ie shows me the picture but when i call `127.0.0.1/fa/default.aspx` i get this error :

[image]

Here is my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="BaHamayeshban" connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog= hamayeshban.ir_conf.qums;integrate security=true;"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit"/>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit"/>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0"/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0"/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
    </handlers>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824"/>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576"/>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
  </system.web>

</configuration>
```

actually the IIS doesn't show me the resource of the error ,and i couldn't find the error  resource.

Here is the iis folder

[image]
Best regards

Comment: Can you quickly try browsing this page from IIS!! So that if there are any typos in the URL, they are corrected.

Comment: @Lucky what do you  mean ?I copied my published file to server .

Comment: Open IIS, select the site/folder that you just published, select the file from the content views.

Comment: @Lucky just call this url :http://217.218.234.188/fa/default.aspx

Comment: Hmm. Try tracing with any URL tracking utilities such as Fiddler. Even before that enable the custom errors in the config file.

Comment: @Lucky i can't open the file directly .

Comment: Do you have acces to the server you have published to?

Comment: @meJustAndrew yes i have

Comment: @meJustAndrew i make a remote connection desktop to it

Comment: make sure your server firewall is off because sometime that also caused problem .

Comment: @sanjayradadiya i don't access the page in the IE of the server ,

Answer (score 0):

where is your **webconfig**? in order to make it work you have to put at least one weconfig file at project level
put webconfig file here 
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Fa\ **Web.config**